# Highcharts highstock plot with data from php

Tags: php, highcharts

Trying to recreate a simple example of html page with a Highstock plot with no success. Seem to do the same thing as in multiple examples I found online, but the plot is still empty.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <title>This is title</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
          var options = {
            chart: {
              renderTo: 'container',
              defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
              marginRight: 130,
              marginBottom: 25,
            },

            title: {
              text: 'test plot'
            },

             xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                categories: []
            },

             yAxis: {
              text: 'value'
            },

            series: [{name:'myline',data:'<?php $data = array(2,3,1,4); echo json_encode($data) ?>'}]

          }

          chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

   });
   </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I change the `series` line to

```
series: [{name:'myline',data:[2,3,1,4]}]
```

it works. So, the problem must be on this line and with the php script.

However, I can't make it to work with php. Tried printing a string with properly formatted numbers, `json_encrode` and some other things, but can't seem to make it work. All I see in such case is chart with no line on it. Printing out result from php execution script doesn't seem to produce the output of the script as well, only an empty line... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a stupid mistake due to the fact that I'm a noob in this. I had to set up a web server on my computer (I used [LAMP](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/486)) and put my php file into /var/www/ directory. Apter that this `data:<?php $data = array(2,3,1,4); echo json_encode($data); ?>` works as it should.